# Header data for webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-core

I'm new here and I need to make a connection from my company's web service to the site I'm creating. So I need to pass information from the user and the device that is being accessed through the header, as it is done in the app (which is ready). I am not able to pass this information through it except through parameters, via get. Could someone help me with this?

This is my index.cshtml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Net.Http;
using BibliotecasGerais;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace wV11.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private string idMobile = (data);
        private string deviceID = (data);
        private string sistema = (data);

        public void OnPost(string numeroSerie, string user, string pass)
        {
            numeroSerie = MobGeral.CriptografarTexto(numeroSerie);
            idMobile = MobGeral.CriptografarTexto(idMobile);
            deviceID = MobGeral.CriptografarTexto(deviceID);
            sistema = MobGeral.CriptografarTexto(sistema);

            WebClient dadosHeaders = new WebClient();

            dadosHeaders.Headers.Add("numeroSerie", numeroSerie);
            dadosHeaders.Headers.Add("sistema", sistema);
            dadosHeaders.Headers.Add("idMobile", idMobile);
            dadosHeaders.Headers.Add("deviceID", deviceID);

            Request.Headers.Add("numeroSerie", numeroSerie);
            Request.Headers.Add("sistema", sistema);
            Request.Headers.Add("idMobile", idMobile);
            Request.Headers.Add("deviceID", deviceID);

            Response.Redirect("http://ws1.versa.com.br:8083/wslic/check/?numeroSerie=" + numeroSerie + "&sistema=" + sistema + "&idMobile=" + idMobile + "&deviceID=" + deviceID + "&user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot redirect with headers. You probably have to issue the request using your WebClient and pass the response as a response to the current request.